# So fat is he ... So beholden is he to ... -- Grammar Question

Tags: adverbs, inversion

> Sikorski is outspoken but not alone. Powerful officials inside Russia also see a darker cast to the regime, with the influence of the free-market economists and loyal oligarchs whom Putin once surrounded himself with significantly diminished. The liberals, relatively speaking, are out; the Russian president is reportedly now only working closely with security officials and the Defense Ministry. Some European diplomats even question whether Putin is still fully in charge, **so beholden** is he to the siloviki – the military and security establishment. “Every year the ruling circle shrinks smaller and smaller,” said one Kremlin source. “The only people that Putin is listening to are the military and the intelligence.”

How do you really understand that type of phrasing? How should one read it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Some European diplomats even question whether Putin is still fully in charge, so beholden is he to the Siloviki – the military and security establishment.

If you're *beholden* to someone, it means they did something for you, and now you owe them your loyalty, or you owe them favours.

I don't think that the word *beholden* is making the sentence difficult to understand. The word *so* is causing all the problems here!

This kind of *so* normally occurs before adjectives or adverbs at the end of a verb phrase:

- He has messed it up **so badly**
- The baboons ate **so much**
- Putin is **so beholden to the Siloviki**

Ususally we add another clause to sentences like these, because we need to understand *how* badly he messed it up, *how* much the baboons ate, or *how* beholden Putin is:

- He has messed it up so badly *he was fired*.
- The baboons ate so much *they couldn't move*.
- Putin is so beholden to the Siloviki *some European diplomats even question whether he is still fully in charge*.

This adverb *so* always modifies another adjective or adverb.  Now, if we want to, we can move this Adjective Phrase or Adverb Phrase to the front of the sentence - but it changes the word order in the rest of the sentence:

- So badly **has he** messed it up that ...
- So much **did the baboons** eat that ...
- So beholden to the Siloviki **is Putin** that ...

When we move the Phrase with *so* to the beginning of the sentence, it makes the subject and the auxiliary verb change places. The sentence will look a bit like a question! But: *IT ISN'T A QUESTION!!!* It only has an unusual word order because we moved the phrase with *so* to the beginning of the sentence.

We can also change the sentences round so that the *So ....* part becomes a subordinate clause at the end of the sentence:

- He was fired, so badly did he mess up.
- The baboons couldn't move, so much did they eat.
- Some European diplomats even question whether Putin is still fully in charge, so beholden is he to the Siloviki.

This is what's happening in the Original Poster's example. The last example above is the example from the Original Poster's question.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

This is an alternate way of structuring this sentence, which you may understand more easily:

> Putin is so beholden to the siloviki that some European diplomats even question whether he is still fully in charge.

It is a variation on the typical *so <adjective> that ...* structure which is used for emphasizing a subject's particular trait.

Answer (score 1):

"Beholden" means "in debt to" or "dependent on". "Debt" here usually doesn't mean owing money, but owing favors. So the writer is saying that Putin is very dependent on the support of the military and intelligence establishments, indeed that he is so dependent on them that he may not really be in charge any more, that these other groups can force him to do what they want.